# How can I avoid using this robot to trigger my JComboBox?

Tags: java, jcombobox, awtrobot

I am using a JComboBox to load a table per the selected item.
The combo box is editable and I am using the autoCompleteDecorator on it.
The problem I was having is all of my code would fire while searching the
combo box instead of waiting for the VK_ENTER.  So, I had to use a variable
to store the string "enter" when the enter key is struck.  Everything is working
ok (bodged together but working) except for me having to strike the enter
key twice to perform commit the selected item..  So instead of the end user
having to strike the key twice, I added a robot.

```
static JComboBox<String> drivers = new JComboBox<String>();
drivers.setEditable(true);
AutoCompleteDecorator.decorate(drivers);

drivers.getEditor().getEditorComponent().addKeyListener(new KeyAdapter() {
    public void keyReleased(KeyEvent kEvent) {
        if (kEvent.getKeyChar() == KeyEvent.VK_ENTER) {
            lastKey="enter";
            try{
                Robot myBot = new Robot();
                myBot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
            }catch (AWTException e){
                JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(frame, "Something has gone terribly wrong.","myBot Failure",JOptionPane.WARNING_MESSAGE);
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    }
});
```

So there is my KeyListener, here is my ActionListener:

```
drivers.addActionListener(new ActionListener(){
    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent eAction){
        if(lastKey=="enter" || !((eAction.getModifiers() & InputEvent.BUTTON1_MASK) == 0)){
            lastKey="";
            //Query the DB, load the table accordingly
            //And do a bunch of other stuff….
        }
    }
}
```

Is there a way for me to eliminate the need for the KeyListener all together?
I suppose what I want to accomplish is only commit the search on the Enter key
press or Left mouse click.

Comment: You should check how to compare Strings correctly and you should think about saving the constant `KeyEvent.VK_ENTER` as `lastKey` instead of a String (in case there is no way to avoid your robot).

Comment: Thanks, @Tom, changed lastKey== to lastKey.equals().. From what I can tell is happening, on the KeyPress event of the ListComponent, it just puts the SelectedItem into the EditorComponent, the second Enter (performed by the Robot) triggers the ActionEvent?  Sorry for my ignorance.

Comment: Don't use KeyListener to monitor changes to the editr, attach an ActionListener to it instead which will do the same job in more platform independent mannaer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using a `KeyListener` to monitor the change to the editor, attach an `ActionListener` to the editor or combobox which will perform the same action in a platform independent manner

Comment: Thank you @MadProgrammer I will give that a shot when I get back to the office tomorrow.